# IO FileStream and StreamReader in Powershell return null while in c# it does work

Tags: c#, powershell, system.io.file

I created a script in C# and for personnal reasons, I would like to convert it in PowerShell.

After many tries, I still can't understand why it still gave me this error, is there something wrong with the code ?

> "**Cannot call a method in a Null expression.**" | when I call $reader.ReadLine()

This script goals is to read a .log file, and to find the usefull information to send them into MongoDB database.

**C#**

```
            string level = "", username = "", date = "", solutionName = "", message = "";
        FileStream logFileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(logFileStream);

        int compteur = 0;

        while (compteur < lineCount-1)
        {
            bool info = true;
            string messagelog = "";
            int tmpCompteur = 0;
            // open the file to read it
            reader = File.OpenText(filePath);
            // take the log message (could be multiple lines)
            for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++)
            {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                if (Regex.IsMatch(line, "INFO") || Regex.IsMatch(line, "ERROR"))
                {
                    if (info)
                        info = !info;
                    else
                        break;
                }
                messagelog += line;
                tmpCompteur++;
                compteur++;
            }

            // Regex to find the log Level, UserName, Date, SolutionName, Message
            if (Regex.IsMatch(messagelog, "INFO") || Regex.IsMatch(messagelog, "ERROR"))
                level = Regex.Match(messagelog, "INFO").Value;
            if (Regex.IsMatch(messagelog, "-(.*?)-"))
                username = Regex.Match(messagelog, "-(.*?)-").Value.Substring(1, Regex.Match(messagelog, "-(.*?)-").Value.Length - 2);
            if (Regex.IsMatch(messagelog, "([1-9]|([012][0-9])|(3[01]))\\/([0]{0,1}[1-9]|1[012])\\/\\d\\d\\d\\d [012]{0,1}[0-9]:[0-6][0-9]:[0-6][0-9]"))
                date = Regex.Match(messagelog, "([1-9]|([012][0-9])|(3[01]))\\/([0]{0,1}[1-9]|1[012])\\/\\d\\d\\d\\d [012]{0,1}[0-9]:[0-6][0-9]:[0-6][0-9]").Value;
            if (Regex.IsMatch(messagelog, "\\[E(.*?)\\]"))
                solutionName = Regex.Match(messagelog, "\\[E(.*?)\\]").Value;
            if (Regex.IsMatch(messagelog, "\\]\\s.*"))
                message = Regex.Match(messagelog, "\\]\\s.*").Value.Substring(2);

            // close the reader because we don't need it anymore
            reader.Close();
            // convert our data to an object to send it to MongoDB
            var Data = new BsonDocument
            {
                { "Date", DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null) },
                { "Level", level},
                { "Message", message},
                { "UserName", username}
            };
            // send data to MongoDB
            collection.InsertOneAsync(Data);
            // delete the lines already processed by our programm
            File.WriteAllLines(filePath, File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Skip(tmpCompteur).ToArray());
        }
        // close the fileStream
        logFileStream.Close();
        // delete the file
        File.Delete(filePath);
    }
```

**PowerShell**

```
   [string]$level
   [string]$userName
   [string]$date
   [string]$solutionName
   [string]$message

   $logFileStream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream $filePath, ([System.IO.FileMode]::Append), ([System.IO.FileAccess]::Write), ([System.IO.FileShare]::Read)
   $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader $logFileStream
   # https://github.com/nightroman/Mdbc
   Connect-Mdbc -ConnectionString $iniContent["MongoDB"]["Server"] -DatabaseName $iniContent["MongoDB"]["Database"] -CollectionName $iniContent["MongoDB"]["Collection"]
   $pbar_LoadFile.Visible = $true
   [int]$compteur = 0
   while ($compteur -clt $linesCount) {

       [bool]$info = $true 
       [string]$messageLog = ""
       [int]$tmpCompteur = 0
       $reader = $IOFile::OpenText($filePath)
       for ([int]$i = 0; $i -lt $linesCount; $i++) {

           $line = $reader.ReadLine() 
           if ($line -match "INFO") {

               if ($info -eq $true) {

                   $info = $false 
               }
               else {
                   break 
               }
           }
           $messageLog += $line 
           $tmpCompteur++
           $compteur++ 
       }


       if ($messageLog -match "INFO") {

           $level = $matches[0]
       }
       if ($messageLog -match "-(.*?)-") {

           $userName = $matches[0].Substring(1, $matches[0].length - 2)
       }
       if ($messageLog -match "([1-9]|([012][0-9])|(3[01]))\/([0]{0,1}[1-9]|1[012])\/\d\d\d\d [012]{0,1}[0-9]:[0-6][0-9]:[0-6][0-9]") {

           $date = $matches[0]
       }
       if ($messageLog -match "    ") {

           $solutionName = $matches[0]
       }
       if ($messageLog -match "\]\s.*") {

           $message = $matches[0].Substring(2) 
       }
       $reader.Close()       
       @{Date = Convert-ToDateTime($date); Level = $level; Message = $message; UserName = $userName } | Add-MdbcData
       (Get-Content $filePath | Select-Object -Skip $tmpCompteur) | Set-Content $filePath
   }
   $logFileStream.Close()
   Remove-Item $filePath
   $pbar_LoadFile.Value += 1
}
```

Comment: As you making a direct translation from `C#` to `PowerShell`, this looks like pidgin PowerShell... To improve your PowerShell syntax, I recommend you to invest some time in the sophisticated [PowerShell pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7). Generally, you script should stream like: `Get-Content $InFile | ForEach-Object { ... }  | Set-Content $OutFile`

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding System.IO.StreamReader as $IOFile. You have to first declare it inside the $reader like this:

```
$reader = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.StreamReader -ArgumentList $filePath
```

In powershell .NET Types are called like this:

```
[System.IO.File]
```

Their static methods are called by placing two colons after ].

Comment: I forget to write it, but I set it as a variable earlier, $IOFile = [System.IO.File]